# al usar creatividad, que el metodo sea o no recursivo influye?

Tags: java, recursión

Que un método sea estatico o no-estatico influye en alguna medida al implementar recursividad en ese mismo método o no genera diferencia?

Comment: Un método recursivo simplemente es un método que se llama a sí mismo. Ese método (y en general cualquier método) puede ser estático o no estático, ninguno tiene más importancia que el otro. No se si es la respuesta que esperabas, si no es, por favor aclara un poco que es lo que necesitas saber o pon algún ejemplo.

Comment: Un método estático es aquel que NO se ejecuta desde un objeto, es decir que no necesitas una instancia del objeto. Por tanto es indiferente para la recursividad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por responder a la pregunta del título. Para realizar la recursividad simplemente en el método llamas al mismo método que estás implementando. Acuérdate siempre de poner una condición de parada, para que la función no se ejecute demasiadas veces y se te desborde la pila:

```
public class Matematicas {

    public int factorial(int n) throws Exception {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new Exception("El parámetro de entrada debe ser mayor que 0");
        } else if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
        }
    }

    public static int factorialEstatico(int n) throws Exception {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new Exception("El parámetro de entrada debe ser mayor que 0");
        } else if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return n * factorialEstatico(n - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int n1 = new Matematicas().factorial(7);
        int n2 = Matematicas.factorialEstatico(7);
    }
}
```

Fíjate que a la hora de llamar al método recursivo, si no es estático tienes que crear un nuevo objeto de la clase para llamarlo (n1), y si el método es estático tienes que llamarlo usando el nombre de la clase (n2).